# iPhone: How to get CFBundleShortVersionString as an std::string?

Tags: iphone, string, nsstring

I know how to get the CFBundleShortVersionString as an NSString:

`NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];`

how do I get that as an std::string? I want to assign it to a global extern std::string so I'm assuming it should be a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) of `std::string` has been overloaded and can do what you want.  Basically you just need to convert the `NSString` to a `char[]`, and then use the assignment operator to load that `char[]` into a `std::string`.

So something like:

```
std::string versionString = [version UTF8String];
```